# Count how many times a value occurs in a array of objects

Tags: javascript, mapreduce

Suppose I have:

```js
const map1 = [
  { id: 1, res: { a: `1-a`, b: `1-b` } },
  { id: 2, res: { a: `2-a`, b: `2-b`, c: `2-c`, d: `2-d` } },
  { id: 3, res: { a: `3-a`, b: `3-b`, c: `3-c` } }
]
const map2 = [
  { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'b' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'a' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'a' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b' } },
  { map1: { 2: 'd',         3: 'a' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'c' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'b', 2: 'd', 3: 'c' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'b',         3: 'a' } }
]
```

This is the result I would like to obtain:

```js
const result = { 
  1: { a: 4, b: 3 }, 
  2: { a: 2, b: 0, c: 3, d: 1 }, 
  3: { a: 3, b: 2, c: 2 } 
}
```

`result` is an object whose keys are `map1` `id`s and values are objects containing the cumulative sum.
For example:

`result[2] = { a: 2, b: 0, c: 3, d: 1 }` because looping each object inside `map2.map1` and looking at value with key `2` (2 because we are looking for result[2]) there are 2 times `a`, 0 times `b`, 3 times `c` and 1 time `d`.

I suppose I have to use `reduce` but how? It seems too complicate to me..
Here my starting point:

```js
const results = map2.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  // ??  
  return accumulator
}, [])
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are counting. The statement `result[2] is { a: 2, b: 0, c: 3, d: 1 } because looping map2 and looking at each object (inside map1) with key 2 there are 2 times a, 0 times b, 3 times c and 1 time d.` is not recognisable  - what make the key===2?

Comment: @mplungjan Thak you for you answer. It's a bit complicated to explain but I tried to do it better in the main message

Comment: In the result, do you want the ones with a count of `0` or not? The example does not make this clear. Why is there no `c: 0, d: 0` in `result[1]` but there is a `b: 0` in `result[2]`?

Comment: @whitecircle should `d: 1` be `d: 2`, since `2: 'd'` appears in two objects?

Comment: @JimNilsson because the first object in `map1` has only `a` and `b`, no `c` or `d`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```js
const result = map1.reduce((counterAcc, m1) => {
  const { id, res } = m1
  const resIds = Object.keys(res)
  const res2Ids = map2.map(({ map1 }) => map1[id])
  const res2IdsWithoutUndefined = res2Ids.filter(Boolean)
  
  counterAcc[id] = resIds.reduce((accumulator, resId) => {    
    accumulator[resId] = 0
    const counterBy = res2IdsWithoutUndefined.reduce((resAcc, ansId) => {
      const answerText = { text: res[ansId] }
      if (!resAcc[ansId]) {
        resAcc[ansId] = 1
      } else {
        resAcc[ansId] += 1
      }
      return resAcc;
    }, {})
    
    return { ...accumulator, ...counterBy }
  }, {})
  return counterAcc
}, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a combination of `reduce`, `map` and `filter` methods.

```js
const map1 = [{"id":1,"res":{"a":"1-a","b":"1-b"}},{"id":2,"res":{"a":"2-a","b":"2-b","c":"2-c","d":"2-d"}},{"id":3,"res":{"a":"3-a","b":"3-b","c":"3-c"}}]
const map2 = [{"map1":{"1":"a","2":"c","3":"b"}},{"map1":{"1":"b","2":"c","3":"a"}},{"map1":{"1":"a","2":"a"}},{"map1":{"1":"a","2":"a","3":"b"}},{"map1":{"2":"d","3":"a"}},{"map1":{"1":"a","2":"c","3":"c"}},{"map1":{"1":"b","2":"d","3":"c"}},{"map1":{"1":"b","3":"a"}}]

const result = map1.reduce((r, { id }) => {
  r[id] = map2
    .map(({ map1 }) => map1[id])
    .filter(Boolean)
    .reduce((a, e) => {
      if (!a[e]) a[e] = 0;
      a[e] += 1
      return a
    }, {})

  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I like your solution! Only one thing: in `result[2]` is missing `b: 0`..

Comment: @whitecircle This solution does not use `res` data from `map1` so there will be no properties with value of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a lookup table for quick retrieval by looping over `map2` to create an object which is keyed by by `1-a`, `2-b`, etc. where each value stores the count/occurrences of each key. Then, once you have the lookup table, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on your `map1` to build your resulting object using the previously build lookup table.

```js
const map1 = [
  { id: 1, res: { a: `1-a`, b: `1-b` } },
  { id: 2, res: { a: `2-a`, b: `2-b`, c: `2-c`, d: `2-d` } },
  { id: 3, res: { a: `3-a`, b: `3-b`, c: `3-c` } }
]
const map2 = [
  { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'b' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'a' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'a' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b' } },
  { map1: { 2: 'd',         3: 'a' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'c' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'b', 2: 'd', 3: 'c' } },
  { map1: { 1: 'b',         3: 'a' } }
];


const summed = map2.reduce((acc, {map1}) => {
  Object.entries(map1).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    acc[`${key}-${val}`] = (acc[`${key}-${val}`] || 0) +1;
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.fromEntries(map1.map(({id, res}) => [
  id,
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(res).map(([key, val]) => [key, summed[val] || 0]))
]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count all key/value pairs of `map2` and generate the wanted result from `map1`.

This approach takes only **one loop** for every given array.

```js
const
    map1 = [{ id: 1, res: { a: `1-a`, b: `1-b` } }, { id: 2, res: { a: `2-a`, b: `2-b`, c: `2-c`, d: `2-d` } }, { id: 3, res: { a: `3-a`, b: `3-b`, c: `3-c` } }],
    map2 = [{ map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'b' } }, { map1: { 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'a' } }, { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'a' } }, { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b' } }, { map1: { 2: 'd', 3: 'a' } }, { map1: { 1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'c' } }, { map1: { 1: 'b', 2: 'd', 3: 'c' } }, { map1: { 1: 'b', 3: 'a' } }],
    temp = map2.reduce((r, { map1 }) => {
        Object.entries(map1).forEach(e => (k => r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + 1)(e.join('-')));
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = map1.reduce((r, { id, res }) => {
        r[id] ??= {};
        Object.entries(res).forEach(([k, v]) => r[id][k] = temp[v] || 0);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```